# ts(1170) error with mapped type when a new property is added

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
enum A {
    FOO = 0,
    BAR = 1,
    BAZ = 2
}
type B = {
    [key in A]: number
}
declare let b: B;
```

It works fine. I can use `b[A.FOO]` but not `b[123]`. However, I'd like to also be able to use `b.length`, but when I add a property to type `B`, like so...

```
type B = {
    length: number,
    [key in A]: number
}
```

...I get the following errors

```
A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1170)
A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.ts(2464)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `type B = {[key in A]?: number}&{lengh:number}` will that work for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have discovered that a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) of the form `{[K in XXX]: YYY}` does not allow additional properties.  Luckily, you can get the same effect by using an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types); an intersection of two object types has all the properties from both:

```
type B = {
    [key in A]: number
} & { length: number };
```

In your specific case, since all these properties are of type `number`, you could also use a single mapped type where the key type is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the `A` enum values and the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"length"`:

```
type B = {
    [key in A | "length"]: number;
}
```

Both versions will work as you desire:

```
let b: B = {
    [A.FOO]: 12,
    [A.BAR]: 34,
    [A.BAZ]: 56,
    length: 78
} // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAglDeAoKKoDEDyGoF4oAYAaZVAIRgCVcoBGY1KcgLWoCZEBfRRAFwE8ADsEY1qSBgG0A1sD5QAliFgBdAFxRwEAEbAATpygAyBFAA2oAOY8AFus07dUDgG5u5nlC011pUXnGoEjAAdJgYarSs9IEh5BQRAMwALNEoQcHMEQCsAGypZpY26gDsAByc3PxCjKxiJGkycoqwUAA+UABE5iBW1h0R9nquXIjunqw+tf71UOlhETRRM+lxiSnLsTBM2Xkz3b0l5SNAA)